# IRepository Pattern

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

For some reason, you always get people in life who know something but don't like to explain them - so I have come here in hope to gain some light into what the IRepository Pattern is.

I have about 1 years programming experience and would like for someone to clearly explain to newbies like me how the above pattern works.

I have had mixed messages from several sources and I am now starting to get *%&^$ confused. However, what I have noticed is that often when mentioning the IRepository pattern, other familiar terms are also mentioned such as **Domain, Domain Objects, Domain Model, Application Services, Domain Services, Web Services**..

Could anybody give an explanation (not massivley in depth but enough to get a good enough picture of what each component means)...please share your experience!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx

Comment: it also makes Dependency Injection and Unit Testing so amazingly easy and nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The repository pattern is normally discussed as part of [domain driven design](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/domain-driven-design-quickly) (DDD).

*The following is over-simplified to get to the point.*

DDD is an architecture for constructing applications. In it the developer will define models that mimic the business requirements. For instance, if you're building an e-commerce application you'd have a product model and a cart model (among other things).

In this architecture the repositories are responsible for persisting and retrieving models. After a visitor to our site adds a product to his/her cart we'd construct the cart object `var cart = new Cart(sessionId, productId, yada...)` then call `repository.Save(cart)`.

### To answer your question:

The `IRepository` and more likely `IRepository<T>` interfaces are used to simplify your repositories. They typically contain methods like `Get(int id)` and `Save(object o)` that aren't going to change whether you're saving a product or a cart (remember, all the information is in the model). In this type of application you'd use one repository to handle all your persistance and only create specialized repositories (e.g. `CartRepository`) for very specific uses.

Another part of DDD is that the application doesn't care where the models are persisted, just that they are persisted. By creating an interface the application can be configured to persist objects to whatever/wherever without having to change code. In our example application we could have `SQLServerRepository`, `OracleRepository`, `XmlRepository`, and `MongoRepository`. As long as they implement the IRepository interface our shopping cart will be able to persist (save) objects to a variety of databases or to an XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here, for the best explanations about Repositories, Domain, etc...
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design
http://domaindrivendesign.org
http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/domain-driven-design-quickly

Comment: My literature tip when it comes to domain driven design and application design/architecture in general: "Domain Driven Design" by Eric Evans, "Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture" by Martin Fowler, "Applying Domain-Driven Design and Patterns" by Jimmy Nielsson and "Clean Code" by Robert Martin. Pick up those and you'll create better software.

Answer (score 0):

Key to understanding mentioned terms is [Domain Driven Design](http://domaindrivendesign.org/resources/what_is_ddd). There is a good book [Domain Driven Design by Eric Evans](http://domaindrivendesign.org/books/evans_2003). Domain Driven Design is not a standard, not a technology or methodology. It's set of practices in software development. If you will keep these practices you will have some benefits. Benefits will be not in decreasing time for development, not in using some tools, but in maintainability of your code, in testability and so on.
Model is representation of some things from real world. Your goal is to keep the model clean, to do not allow to influence of programming technologies, of data storage restrictions. In this context is important to use Repository pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give a short example of how I use the IReporisotry pattern. Don't take this explanation as "the way of using it", this is just an example.

I have a Silverlight app wich uses EntityFramework on the server side to access the database. I don't know if you are familiar with EntityFramework but among other features it gives you a `context` where your entities are so you have ask the context for entitites or tell the context to save entities to the database.

That context has many Repositories to handle those entitites. So my app has a SQLReporsitory (implementing my IRepository) that 'knows' how to save entities to the database. So why the heck I implemented the IRepository? Because I also need to test the saving and retrieving of my entities and I can't afford to depend of the data in the database. So I created a "Memory Database" wich holds simple `List<T>` of entities and knows how to add, retrieve and remove entities from those lists.

So, when I'm running the app, the SqlRepository gets created, and when I'm running the tests the Fake Repository gets created. And the core of my business is not changed at all. I just 'ask' for an entity or whatever and depending on the context where I'm running I get the data from the database or from my in memory database.

Hope it helps

**Edit:** here's a good example, with code! http://azurecoding.net/blogs/brownie/archive/2010/09/22/irepository-lt-t-gt-and-iunitofwork.aspx

Answer (score -1):

In short, IRepository is an **anti-pattern** -> http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2009/01/16/ddd-the-generic-repository/

In C#/.net land there is a great drive to overcomplicate / overdesign programs, even the simplest of CRUD-application has to be DDD and have a domain model and offcourse (wrongly) have a generic repository. Cargo Cult Programming at its finest

You can find a good resource for reviews of overdesigned architectures @ http://ayende.com/blog/tags/reviews